# login and authentication in nextjs with httponly cookies

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Hi i am building an application on the react with nextjs 
I am calling login API from my client side on that I get a token I want to send to nextjs server and set httponly cookie of that auth token so no client side script has access to that token on logout I want to destroy that cookie

my question  is that how to achieve this practically

or do you have any other suggestion of login and authorization with react and nextjs

Answer (score 9):

Practically it looks like in the following steps:

1. You need create api endpoint in your nextjs app in pages folder.
   For login it could be like this `pages/api/login/index.js`
2. In this file you need create logic for requesting data from external api
3. On client side make request to your next api endpoint `...fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/login', options)`
4. When this request came from the client your code in `pages/api/login/index.js` fetch login data from external api and after success set cookie with httpOnly flag:

   `import { setCookie } from 'nookies' ... setCookie({ res }, 'name', 'value', { secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production', maxAge: 72576000, httpOnly: true, path: '/' })`

Comment: Perfect, you just helped me a ton!

Comment: This works but is this a good practise?